# Which entity should be responsible for sending messages through the message broker?

Tags: typescript, oop, architecture, rabbitmq

I'm wondering which entity should send over messages through the message broker, in this example it's `RabbitMQ`. The question is the following: Should the `Controller` class or the `Service` class be responsible for publishing the event to the `Message Broker`?

I'm not sure if there is any standard or best practice for the current problem.

As far as I can deduce:

- If we make the `Controller` responsible for sending the message then we might encounter a lot of duplicated code and when a change arrives we'll need to change it everywhere we've made the call.
- If we make the `Service` responsible for sending the message we might encounter cases where we might not want to send a message over through the `Message Broker` and that will force us to include a flag argument, which will force us to design almost every `Service` method so that it includes that flag argument.

Code examples:
Controller sending over the message:

```js
class ExampleController {
  constructor(
    private readonly exampleService: ExampleService,
    private readonly rabbitMQ: RabbitMQ,
  ) {
  }

  async index() {
    await this.exampleService.thing();
    await this.rabbitMQ.sendMessage(...)
  }
}

class ExampleService {
  async thing() {
  //  . . .
  }
}
```

Service sending over the message:

```js
class ExampleController {
  constructor(
    private readonly exampleService: ExampleService,
  ) {
  }

  index() {
    await this.exampleService.thing();
  }
}

class ExampleService {
  constructor(
    private readonly rabbitMQ: RabbitMQ,
  ) {
  }

  async thing() {
    // . . .
    this.rabbitMQ.sendMessage(...)
  }
}
```